# How Scalable is OpenERP? Are there Any Statistics Availble?

Tags: scalability, odoo

OpenERP user manual Says 'Open ERP was developed mainly for small and medium-sized organizations with 5 to 150 users. ' I want to Implement OpenERP in an Educational Institution, where more than 150 can be active simultaneously. OpenERP

Is OpenERP Worth the effort for such an Implementation?
I know there will be bottlenecks but are there any official or unofficial statistics available?

a similar was asked by at [How scalable is OpenERP?](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/How-scalable-is-OpenERP-165657.S.176069974)
How does OpenERP perform with large deployments and what do you need to do to really scale it to enterprise level - 1000+ users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a post floating around about a production instance of OpenERP that has 150,000 users, 100 http queries per second, and over 1,000,000 product codes.  I could not verify the origin.

I can tell you that 1000 users, on a non-media rich implementation would not be hard at all.  Run the web app on something like ubuntu 12.4, and run the postgresql on a DB server instance separate from the application.  If you see repetitive queries slowing down response time install an instance of memcached on a server for quicker reference times for users.

You could probably even do 1000 users on a stack depending on how many concurrent users and queries you would see.